# Sleeping an Async Thread: Is It a Good Practise?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous

There is a database access operation executing on an async thread. After the results are obtained, this thread signals the main thread to do something with the data. But 2 seconds after signaling I have to check if main thread is able to proccess the data, if not I should clear it. The question is should I make the async thread sleep after signaling, then do the check operation  or make async thread set up a timer after signaling to start another async thread to do check operation?

Comment: You should call yield and not sleep. Sleep will prevent the main even loop or other threads to be executed since the whole native thread will be yield delaying operations. There is a slight chance sleep in Python do a yield but it would be quite surprising.

Comment: Im already executing a long running operation on that async thread. It didnt block other threads or the main thread.